# Book reference does not appear in the article

Tags: cross-referencing, books

I use:
\usepackage{natbib}
\bibliographystyle{elsarticle-num}

before beginning the document and \bibliography{mybibfile} before ending. The articles work well, but the books reference does not work. ?? sign is appeared for the book references.

What should I do?

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! Did you run the cycle `(pdf)latex->bibtex->(pdf)latex (twice)`?

Comment: Do you get errors or warnings when running BibTeX?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Like Bernard already mentioned, have you compiled your work with 'bibtex'? That's needed for Latex to realize that the .bib-File was changed. Often you have to compile `PdfLatex + Bib(La)tex + PdfLatex + PdfLatex` to see changes in your bibliography.
2. Your bibliography will only list those articles/books that are already quoted in your text. Look if you have a reference (`\cite{book}` or `\citep{book}` ) for those books that are missing. (A few days ago that happened to me. I used `\cite{}` instead of `\citep{}` but I got no Error, only the reference hadn't worked.)
3. (edit) Maybe also possible: look if there are some special characters in the descriptions of your books. Like the book title. Symbols like `& ä û` can cause problems (but you should get some errors here).

Comment: How is it different from previous answer?

Comment: Given that the OP has stated that the document contains the instructions ` \usepackage{natbib}` and `\bibliographystyle{elsarticle-num}`, your advice to employ the `biblatex` package does not seem to have a chance of being useful. (One cannot load both `natbib` and `biblatex` in a document.) In addition, `biblatex` is a package, not an executable program. Hence, telling the OP to run `BibLatex` has no meaning at all. Did you maybe mean to write that the author should run either BibTeX or Biber?

Comment: Mico, no I don't want to recommend an other package. Something like that often causes just other problems... but yes I forgot to add to add the braces. Some Tex-Editors are showing the commands like this: ```bib(la)tex``` (eg. TexMaker), so I wanted it to look identical to what a user is used to see. I edited my answer, ty :)